# Count entries based on exponential notation values with pure awk

Tags: awk, exponential, notation

I am trying to count the entries that are less than the e threshold of 1e-5 in my tab-del data file that looks something like the table below.

> col1 col2 col3 eval
>
> entry1 - - 1e-10
>
> entry2 - - -
>
> entry3 - - 0.001

I used this code:

```
$: awk -F"\t" '{print $4}' table.txt | awk '($1 + 0) < 1e-5' | grep [0-9*] | wc -l
```

This outputs:

```
$: 1
```

While this works, I would like to improve the command into something pure awk. I would love to know how to do this in awk. Also, I would like to know how to print the line that satisfies the threshold if this is possible. Thank for helping!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot see what you are trying to attempt in the above code. Your code does not make a lot of sense. Are you trying to count all values in the last column which are below a given threshold? Do you want the value to be written in E-notation? Do you consider a difference between `0.001` and `1E-3`? Adding `0` to `$1` will convert any non-numeric values to `0` and therefore your comparison will always be successful. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] and take a look at [tour].

Comment: Hi! I edited my question. Yes, I wanted to count the number of rows with < 1e-05.  No, I am not trying to write the value in E-notation. Apparently, the second awk could take into account the difference between 1e-3 and 0.001. Also, the dash or blank entries remained as is after the second awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the best way:

```
awk -F"\t" '($4+0==$4) && ($4 < 1E-5){c++}END{print c}' file
```

This does the following:

- **`($4+0==$4)`:** first conditional to check if `$4` is a number.
- **`($4<1E-5)`:** second conditional to check if the value matches the range
- **`&&`:** If both conditions are satisfied, increment a counter `c`
- at the `END`, print the value of `c`

Be aware that your `grep` in your original command will fail. If `$4` in the original file would read like `XXX1XXX` (i.e. a string with a number in it) or `XXX*XXX` (i.e. a string with an asterisk in it), it would be counted as a match.

Comment: the grep will also not behave as intended if glob matching causes filename expansion - always quote shell metacharacters